AWK command not working as expected giving & data as output
I have file where I need to find if some column is empty. File is delimited by ;
Some of data contains & in word and awk is command it not working for same .
Lets say I have file (dedup_company_output.txt file name) which has following data:
"c1";"c2";"c3";"c4";"c5"
900;"DAVIES TURNER &AMP; CO LTD";;315235;1
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;444;1
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;;1

Now in first line I am not sure why we are getting &AMP; for & and hence when I am running following command it is giving me incorrect result .
awk -F';' '$4 == ""' dedup_company_output.txt> result.txt

As as output I am getting
900;"DAVIES TURNER &AMP; CO LTD";;315235;1
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;;1

where as I was expecting only
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;;1

Do I need to change something in this command to include & as part of word or do I need to change the file?

Not clear and crossposted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79227624/awk-command-not-working-as-expected-giving-data-as-output#79227624

it's not the &, it's the ;. Plain AWK doesn't deal with that, you'll need awk --csv (with e.g. GNU AWK), or change &AMP; -> & first, and then back (if that's the only such special string)

what is best way to change & -> &

That's not necessary to isolate fields and you'd need to isolate fields first before you could robustly change &AMP; to & inside fields otherwise you could accidentally change foo,"a &AMP; b";bar;&AMP;etc to foo,"a & b";bar;&etc instead of foo,"a & b";bar;&AMP;etc

&amp; is the html encoding to display an &, so you should first search and replace &amp; and &AMP; by & . For exemple : sed -e 's/&amp;/\&/' <file >new_file . Within awk it is not as simple apparently, as "&" or "&" as target in a sub are still considered as "&" and is thus citing back the whole thing matched by the regex... Using \xxx would necessitate you to be in the correct locale... use sed ^^

@EdMorton : I tried to use, in awk, sub("&amp;",  "\&", $0) as pre-processing, but it treats the \& as & and thus subs to &amp; (it does match as if I do sub("&amp,", "[&]", $0) I get [&amp;]  back) ... How to sub to & instead, wihout using the \octal form (too depending on the user's locale) ? (or should we use match and substr instead?)

@OlivierDulac you need to double escape & in the replacement, i.e."\\&" instead of "\&", see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Gory-Details for why.

Using mlr:
$ mlr --csv -N --fs=";" filter '$4 == ""' file
$ mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output --fs=";" filter '$c4 == ""' file #For filtering using headers
$ mlr --csv -N --fs semicolon filter 'is_empty($4)' file

Using -N for a csv file will add numeric headers like 1,2.etc as with --implicit-csv-header but -N doesn't print header row. With this $4th field can be used like awk command.
The second command uses header $c4 for filtering. With --headerless-csv-output it doesn't output header row.
The third command uses built-in DSL function is_empty()¹ that's self explanatory (As suggested by @Kusalananda).
As suggested by @AdminBee csv aware tool should be used.
About put and filter subcommands:

The essential usages of mlr filter and mlr put are for record-selection and record-updating expressions, respectively.

And

Expressions sent to mlr filter must end with a boolean expression, which is the filtering criterion.


¹
is_empty (class=typing #args=1): True if field is present in input with empty string value, false otherwise.
Taken from the manual.

The &AMP is irrelevant, the ; inside the quotes is what's causing your script to fail. There are a lot of ways to deal with this but the simplest way when you only have some earlier fields that might be quoted and contain the FS as in your case is to count fields from the end rather than from the front, e.g. using any awk:
$ awk -F';' '$(NF-1) == ""' dedup_company_output.txt
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;;1

If that's not all you need or you want to learn more about the issue then see whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk for more information.

Upvoted. And thanks for sharing the other answer by you.

You've defined the input field separator as ; but this character also shows up as data thus leading awk to think the following line actually has 6 fields:
900;"DAVIES TURNER &AMP; CO LTD";;315235;1
   ^                   ^        ^^      ^

NOTES:

awk sees 5 ; characters (not the 4 as seen in the other lines)
awk sees the 3rd, 4th and 5th fields as  CO LTD", >empty< and 325235, respectively
since the 4th field is >empty< ($4=="") this line shows up in your output

If you're using GNU awk 4.0+ you can make use of the FPAT variable to define fields by content (as opposed to -F which defines fields by delimiter). In this case you want to tell (g)awk the fields are delimited by semicolons and wrapped in optional double quotes, while also allowing the semicolon to show up as data.
One awk idea for this case:
awk '
BEGIN    { FPAT = "([^;]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" }
$4 == ""
' input.txt

#######
# or as a one-liner

awk 'BEGIN {FPAT = "([^;]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"} $4==""' input.txt

This generates:
909;"DAVIES TURNER CO LTD";;;1


The problem here is that you are dealing with a "non-simple" CSV file, where the separator character can be present inside fields (which then will be quoted).
In your example on line 2, the & is represented as &AMP;, and this closing ; is mis-interpreted by awk as field seperator. So for this line, it considers "DAVIES TURNER &AMP to be the second field,  CO LTD" to be the third, and the fourth one empty. This gives the false match.
If you want to use awk, you should probably consider changing the source file to not escape special characters, or change the field delimiter to something other than ;.
Alternatively, you could use a tool such as miller for dealing with full-fledged CSV files.
